# How to fix icons in Windows 10

Tags: windows, icons

I have upgraded from Windows 7 to Windows 10. In various Windows Store Apps I see boxes instead of icons in their interfaces.

[image]

How do I fix this? Is there any font missing?

Comment: As for problem in the image that indicates system files that are corrupt.  I would run the DISM and SFC tools to repair it.  Be sure any language packs you had installed while running Windows 7 are installed again.

Comment: I run SFC command and it said that it didn't find any integrity violation problem.

Comment: DISM page  (https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh825236.aspx) says it is used in OS till Windows 8.1 (Windows 10 is not written there)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem fixed by upgrading Windows 10 to Threshold 2